# multiple row per case dataset to single row per case dataset

Tags: r, reshape

I have a dataset as follows:

```
ikn   arrivaldate  LOS
1     06MAR2007    10
1     21FEB2007    1
2     14FEB2007    16
3     15FEB2008    23
3     02MAR2008    5
3     15MAR2008    68


data$arrivaldate <- as.Date(data$arrivaldate, format="%d%m%y")
```

The "arrivaldate" is a string variable.

I Used as.date to convert the string variable to date. But I got "NA" as arrivaldate. I don't know what the issue is.

Second, is there a way that I can convert this multiple row per case dataset to a single row per case dataset in a way that instead of having multiple arrivaldates, having arrivaldate1, arrivaldate2, arrivaldate3 as new variables. The number of these new variables should be max of the duplicate cases in the dataset (3 in the sample dataset that i provided).

I appreciate if someone can assist me with these issues.

```
ikn  arrivaldate1  LOS1  arrivalsate2  LOS2  arrivaldate3  LOS3                      
1     06MAR2007     10    21FEB2007     1         NA         NA           
2     14FEB2007     16        NA        NA        NA         NA          
3     15FEB2008     23    02MAR2008     5      15MAR2008     68
```

Comment: For this sample input, can you share your desired output? It's not quite clear from your description. Also, fixing the date is easy with `format = "%d%b%Y"`.

Comment: by duplicate cases I mean the multiple cases per case.

Comment: Please *edit* your question with further details.  Don't put them in the comments where the formatting options are limited.

Comment: I tried format = "%d%b%Y". However it didn't work. The new dates don't make sense. for "06MAR2007" I have 2020-03-06. It seems all the days and months are correct. However, I have 2020 for all the years.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the second question is "not elegantly". Think about it; what you're asking for is columns of arrival_date1, arrival_date2, arrival_date3. Problem: what if an ikn only has one arrival date? What goes in those columns? You're going to end up with a ton of NAs, at best.

Depending on what you intend to do with the data (it's not quite clear from your example - perhaps you could elucidate?) having arrivaldate as a categorical variable that combines with ikn may be perfectly fine. There's a lot of R libraries built around this format, and in the worst-case scenario, you can run whatever functions/analysis you want through something like [dplyr](http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/) or [data.table](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/). But, without knowing precisely what you want to do, it's hard to tell what you *need* (as opposed to what you're *asking* for).

On the general question of reshaping data, you probably want to look into [tidyr](https://github.com/hadley/tidyr) or [reshape2](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/reshape2/index.html).

Comment: Obligatory [link to a blog post of mine](http://news.mrdwab.com/2012/12/04/what-exactly-is-elegant-code-in-r/)....

Comment: Thanks you very much for your quick response. I think I should think about all these issues now and I will come back to you later with a better story.

Comment: @Mahsa what is the output of: `x <- 0; class(x) <- "Date"; x` ?

Comment: The output is 1970-01-01.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But none of the %b%d%Y and "%d%b%Y" work. The first one give me "NAs" and the second one convert all years to 2020. I even tried origin="1990-01-01" and "1960-01-01" and still all the years are 2020.

Answer (score 0):

Format the date with `%b%d%Y`, and then use `reshape` to get the wide data form *after* you add a secondary "id" variable. This latter part is easily done with `getanID` from my "splitstackshape" package:

```
library(splitstackshape)  ## for getanID

## Format the date
mydf$arrivaldate <- as.Date(mydf$arrivaldate, format="%d%b%Y")

## Reshape
reshape(getanID(mydf, "ikn"), direction = "wide", 
        idvar = "ikn", timevar = ".id")
#    ikn arrivaldate.1 LOS.1 arrivaldate.2 LOS.2 arrivaldate.3 LOS.3
# 1:   1    2007-03-06    10    2007-02-21     1          <NA>    NA
# 2:   2    2007-02-14    16          <NA>    NA          <NA>    NA
# 3:   3    2008-02-15    23    2008-03-02     5    2008-03-15    68
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. But none of the  %b%d%Y and "%d%b%Y" work. The first one give me "NAs" and the second one convert all yeares to 2020.